# Flash player compatible with very old phone browser

Tags: flash

`http://flash.flowplayer.org/download/` doesn't work with [Nokia n82](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_N82). But youtube (flash) works. I want to host video not on yoututbe or else I would use youtube player itself (haven't tested though yet).

Since it's an old phone I'm guessing flowplayer is just incompatible with it. Any other players I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you've tried the latest version of Flowplayer (version 5). This latest version falls back to flash when html5 video is not available. This behavior is the same that YouTube has. Some guy did a nice [list/comparison of the different html5 players](http://praegnanz.de/html5video/). You can check out the [demo page](http://praegnanz.de/html5video/p_flowplayer.php) to see if any of these work for you.